# Flagging comments

Tags: support, flagging

In the context of [this now-closed and deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/a-rather-simple-question), there were a couple of comments by the OP that I thought merited flagging for moderator attention. Much to my surprise, as soon as I flagged them they seemed to disappear.

Is this new behavior associated to "trusted users" (20K+ rep), or did my flagging just happen to coincide with a moderator deleting them?

Comment: I couldn't find much detailed information  on meta.SO, but according [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment) sufficiently many flags cause the deletion of a comment and I guess your flags were simply the ones causing the deletion, independently of your status as a "trusted user". Jeff Atwood mentions some "heuristics" that make it easier for a comment to be "flag[ged] away" and I would say that the language used in those comments I saw should fall under all sorts of such heuristics.

Comment: For the record the original question, also deleted, is [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58144/algebra-simple-questions)

Comment: @Theo: Okay, that explains it. Just coincidence, then. Actually, I like it better that way (i.e., me not having amazing delete-comment powers)

Comment: @Theo: Since your comment did essentially answer my question (my flags just happened to put the comments over-the-top and get deleted), could you post it so I can accept it?

Comment: @Arturo Hmm... polysigns raised to superpowers, imagine how much nicer that would turn out here than sci.math!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment) on meta.SO a certain number of flags causes deletion of the comment. Your flags just happened to be the flags that caused the deletion, independently of your status of a "trusted user".

So the answer is: it was just coincidence.

Unless you are a moderator, you cannot unilaterally delete a comment by flagging.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for posting this.

Comment: @Arturo: No problem, I simply wasn't sure if this would be a satisfactory explanation, that's why I only commented first.

Answer (score 5):

You are listed as the "deletion user" in the moderator view of the comments, so apparently it was your flags that did it. However, I don't know what reputation endows this "super-flag" ability.

---

Deleted comments from the second question:

> **Theo**: Voting to close as not a real question. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)
>
> **Theo**: See also: http://www.simonsingh.net/books/fermats-last-theorem/
>
> **Theo**: @Brian: I'm having a hard time believing this is real. How does one come up with one of the most famous questions in mathematics and be unable to parse the eminently readable first paragraph of the wikipedia article?
>
> **dsadsa**: Theo you are a shining example of math elitist. Spouting about your bulls*** of simple concepts and ideas of math and how only a complete idiot wouldn't understand what a modularity theorem is. Well f*** you, I am so sick of elitist f***s like you. I work so f***ing hard at math, but it just doesn't come easy to me like it does for you.
>
> **dsadsa**: Actually I am not done, I can't stand pieces of s*** like you Theo. You were probably picked on a lot as a kid so now hiding behind the internet you can say whatever you want. It is pathetic, and you are just as bad as them.

Comment: I don't either, and that's the first time it's happened (though I haven't flagged comments in a while). I did a quick attempt at searching in meta.se but did not see any similar questions when I typed "flagging comments".

Comment: @Zev It's quite possible that those FLT questions arose from the recent misinformed [PCMag article on FLT.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/58069/242) So I think one shouldn't be so quick to dismiss the questions as trolling. In particular I think it was wrong to delete the questions. That should be reserved only for unquestionable spam and or off-topic posts. Why wasn't closing sufficient?

Comment: @Bill: I have no qualms about deleting the user after his comments on the second question, although I would have to agree that deleting his original question was a borderline decision. I think that the phrase "fancy math elitist word" is a pretty good indicator of a trouble user, so when another user suggested the possibility of deleting the question, I was already pretty open to the idea (the responsibility is mine, of course). In the future, I will wait longer for feedback. But I think we would gotten a similar outburst from the OP on the original question if it hadn't been deleted.

Comment: I didn't see the first question before commenting on the second one. I didn't buy it from the beginning. So somebody comes along and wants to find a solution for a "simple question" and says "it must be an integer, I believe". Both joriki and I posted a link to FLT, and I said that I voted to close. Then the OP comes back a minute later and says he didn't understand (= no effort). I expressed my puzzlement and was called names in return, thus I decided to remove a link to Singh's page and my other comments and left it at that. I think deletion was completely justified.

Comment: Zev: if you think there's need to display the whole exchange in the comments, feel free to do so. I admit that yet again I haven't acted with enough sensitivity, but I did nothing that would have warranted anything close to such a reaction.

Comment: Somehow the impression I got from reading the now-deleted user's comments is that he's a poor sport...

Comment: @Theo Zev. This is what I see. The OP posted a serious question, but didn't realize that his remark that "I guess and integer is a fancy math elitist word for whole number" would cause his question to be deleted. So he resposted it an hour later without that remark. All seemed to be well till the OP seems to be upset about something that Theo said (which I cannot see since it seems to have been deleted). Theo: what did you say? Deletion seems very heavy handed here. Rather, all that seems necessary is that the offending comments by the OP and/or Theo be deleted, and all would've been well.

Comment: @Bill: I agree that this may be yet another very unfortunate situation. I don't remember the exact wording (that's why I said Zev should post the comments for transparency). I first wrote: I'm voting to close, see *wikipedia page on FLT*. Two or three minutes later the OP comes back and said does that mean there are no solutions and I said. "Yes, this is clearly stated in the first paragraph" and also posted a link to Singhs page since I thout that book might be exactly right for him. The OPs reaction was two now deleted comments featuring many f's plus the ones remaining.

Comment: @Bill: I didn't understand up to now that the "fancy math elitist word" in Zev's comment featured in the first version of the question. I thought this was a way of paraphrasing the way I was called a "f..ing math elitist f...". I never get the PC right.

Comment: @Bill: I've added the deleted comments, with some appropriate asterisks.

Comment: @Zev: thanks, could you display my deleted comments as well, please?

Comment: @Theo Thanks for the clarification. Of course I don't condone the OP's comments. However, I think we could have avoided reaching that point if we had been a bit more sensitive to the fact that the widespread exposure given by Google's front page doodle commemorating Fermat's 410'th birthday would no doubt attract questions from laypersons. I tried to make this known to prevent others from quickly misjudging such questions as trolling but, alas, it appears to have been too late.

Comment: @Bill: As I said, I'm aware that I could have been more sensitive and I'm taking responsibility for part of the outburst. However *if* this particular question was triggered by the 410th then the question would probably have been phrased differently, like "I don't understand what it is about" or whatever. But this guy said "simple algebra question" and pretended he came up with it himself. I just don't buy it.

Comment: @Zev I hadn't seen the deleted comments. Wow, that degenerated exponentially quickly. It appears that the closing/deletion of the prior question left the OP with a big chip on their shoulder. My impression is that it was a serious question. Perhaps we should strive to be a bit more sensitive when a layperson posts such questions. There are indeed lay folks who've never heard of FLT and such folks may turn here for help when they encounter such. There was another FLT-related question a few hours later, and there may well be more. Surely we can tackle such questions without appearing "elitist".

Comment: Out of curiosity: are there deleted comments in the first question? I don't think I can follow the comment thread there.

Comment: @Theo Perhaps your remark was simply the straw that broke the camel's back, after what occurred in the prior question. I think we should strive to welcome  questions at *all* levels, in as friendly a manner as possible.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, I do agree with that and I think I made that sufficiently clear and I'm aware of my deficiency in that respect. What else can I say? My comments prior to the ones of this hour addressed only what I saw in the second question and yes, I've been a bit unwelcoming and maybe even rude. My gut feeling still is that the guy was simply out for a fight.

Comment: @Theo To be sure, my comments are not directed at you but at everyone.  My primary reason for continuing the discussion was the hope that, by dissecting it, we may learn from the experience, to help avoid similar problems in the future. Otoh, we do need to keep an eye out for trolls too, since when sci.math finally bites the dust no doubt some *will* wander our way.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks! Got it. On a completely different note: Could you be so kind as to explain your comment to Arturo "polysigns raised to superpowers" to me? I guess this is sci.math-lingo, with which I'm not familiar at all.

Comment: @Theo On sci.math lives a crank who composes endless math word salads on "polysign" numbers - e.g. see [the sci.math link here to one 670-post thread.](http://bit.ly/mR7P7n) The cranks' extremely disingeneous behavior managed to raise the ire of many folks on sci.math. So, my remark was merely a joke about how such superpowers could have proved *very* useful there (and here too, once he arrives). Alas, the joke was not surreal. I've yet to encounter a surreal crank, but surely one will arrive sooner or later now that there are accessible expositions on surreal numbers.

Comment: @Bill: thanks for the explanation and providing that illustrative example... wow! Thinking that earlier today I was about to lose my patience for a lot less (nothing to do with this thread).

Comment: @Bill You write "Surely we can tackle such questions without appearing "elitist"." Yet, it has been pointed out that the OP came to the site, convinced that it was populated by "math elitists" and wrote it in his very first post on this site. Personally, I think that he got the reaction he deserved, and in the unlikely event that he has more wit than his contribution here suggests, he just might learn something useful for life. Theo is completely blameless and shouldn't think that it was him who created this "math elitist" image in the first place.

Comment: @Alex I have seen many, many comments by folks considering joining Math.SE who have heard through the grapevine that Math.SE is elitist. That opinion does not come out of thin air. Partly it comes from confusion with MO, and partly it comes from real problems such as those discussed above and elsewhere on meta. The first step in solving such problems is acknowledging that they do indeed exist. Your comment is a sad example of such. Also, I don't understand why you are attempting to defend Theo, since nobody "blamed" Theo for anything. Please read more carefully what was written above.

Comment: @Alex: Thank you. I don't think I was unreasonably rude and I don't blame myself or hold myself responsible, but as Bill pointed out *many* times already one can't be too careful with new users. One needs to wear kid's gloves is an expression he used somewhere. The incident is not as clear-cut as it seems, I think. I'm trying to support Bill's pleas, even if I sometimes fail to do so in practice. It is all-too-easy to rub new users the wrong way, and it is at least the [second time](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2262/5363) I was involved in such an incident.

Comment: @Bill: see above.

Comment: @Theo Alas, problems mentioned in that thread still exist, e.g. see the [comments here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/58355/242) where a new user had his faced rubbed in the mud not once, but **three** times for the *huge* sin of questioning imperatively. That's quite sad. This is a math forum, not a Miss Manners column. What's even worse, are the unfounded personal attacks that continue to be directed towards folks who point out these problems. It's no wonder that Math.SE is being widely branded as elitist. If we can't keep such elitist behavior in check then we deserve that badge of shame.

Comment: @Bill My point was that I don't regret alienating someone who comes here to ask whether something is a "fancy math elitist word". If he doesn't return, that's fine by me. I don't like it when people come to ask for help with a sense of entitlement, and I regard is as a fact of life that by doing so, they risk being told to get lost (usually not by me). If they come to a new place with this attitude sufficiently often, they'll learn this fact of life eventually. Also, I read your comment as blaming Theo, albeit in slightly veiled terms: "I think we could have avoided reaching that point if...".

Comment: @Alex I **explicitly** wrote above to Theo: "To be sure, my comments are not directed at you but at everyone". So any misreading of my intent is a product your own imagination. Your above post is yet another example of the elitist attitude at the root of the problems. It *is* our fault that people come here with those impressions, because too few people have the courage to stand up against the few bullies that are responsible for most of the problems.

Comment: @Bill If you see yourself as the courageous bulwark against elitists and bullies, then at least don't keep saying "_we_ could have avoided" and "_our_ fault". But I am sure that you will again deny that that's what you were getting at, and indeed your post is, as so often, sufficiently non-explicit and abstract that you could have meant anyone or noone. Still, I think I am bowing out of this discussion, being called elitist and a bully should be quite enough to get me through the evening.

Comment: @Alex As I said, those our products of your imagination. I think if you spent more time here you would soon realize the veracity of my remarks.

Comment: @Bill: Re: **three** complaints. I saw this comments thread before user3302 left the building. Look: I've seen many such exchanges between you and Arturo. Obviously Arturo is severely bothered by questions formulated in the imperative. His trying to educate people in this respect often strikes me as somewhat quixotesque (if such a word exists in English), but I'm doing similar things by reacting rather briskly to users who reach for apples that obviously hang far too high (maybe another way of contributing to the elitism here).

Comment: @Bill: I would most welcome if you followed up on your earlier intentions ([expressed e.g. here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/the-b-incident/2263#comment-8122)) and opened a separate meta thread on this global issue instead of end- and fruitless debates in comments here and on main.

Comment: @Theo Sorry, but I don't see the point of your prior two comments. It appears to ignore most of the points that I raised. There are many folks besides I who have expressed serious concerns here about about new users being bombarded with critiques about nonmathematical matters. Also I find it a bit contradictory that you seem to imply that it is ok for folks to bombard new users with such nomathematical critiques but that is not ok for others to critique said unwelcoming destructive behavior.

Comment: @Bill: You misread me. After rereading I don't think I made any such implication. I'm not particularly fond of these endless imperative-complaints and I tried to acknowledge at the same time that I'm guilty of insisting on comparable pet-peeves. I also tried to suggest that an explicit discussion of this specific issue would be a more effective way to go. I've seen many exchanges between you and Arturo (and others) as the ones as you linked to. However, I think that clarifying the positions in a focused meta-thread instead of long exchanges in comments might be a more effective way to go.

Comment: @Theo I've been thinking a bit about a proposal for a compromise that would avoid these problems. When I can find some spare time I'll post it in a new thread.

Comment: @Bill: That would be great! To emphasize: there was no sarcasm whatsoever in my comment suggesting that you do this.

Answer (score 3):

There are some heuristics that change the number of flags needed for deletion of a comment, I remember comments about the accept rate to be one category that is easier to delete. I can't find the original meta post and I don't think the details are public.

I'm pretty sure that there is no 20k privilege for that, only moderators have the supervote.